# Using cons with tail of tail in a list throws an error

Tags: haskell, cons

I am a Haskell beginner and I am basically trying to understand why this fails:

```
Prelude> test
[2,3,4,1]
Prelude> tail $ tail test
[4,1]
Prelude> 2 : [4,1]
[2,4,1]
Prelude> 2 : tail $ tail test

<interactive>:27:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Integer] -> t’
                  with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    • The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
      but its type ‘[Integer]’ has none
      In the expression: 2 : tail $ tail test
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = 2 : tail $ tail test
    • Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:27:1)

<interactive>:27:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Integer]’
                  with actual type ‘[a0] -> [a0]’
    • Probable cause: ‘tail’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘tail’
      In the expression: 2 : tail
      In the expression: 2 : tail $ tail test
Prelude>
```

I see the error message "Probable cause: ‘tail’ is applied to too few arguments" but I don't understand enough to know what's causing it because that same expression just worked.

Comment: `2 : tail $ tail test` is equivalent to `(2 : tail) (tail test)`, not `2 : (tail (tail test))`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: That worked! Thank you. As I mentioned in the other answer, I did try `2 : $ tail $ tail test` and it returned `parse error on input ‘$’`. Would you know why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be aware of operator grouping/precedence: `2 : tail $ tail test` isn't the same as "cons 2 onto the value `tail $ tail test`" any more than `5 * 3 + 2` is "multiply the result of `3 + 2` by 5". In both cases, you need to add parentheses if that's the operation you want.

Comment: ah! So I had actually tried:

`2 : $ tail $ tail test`

and that also failed. It was my understanding that $ and putting parenthesis are equivalent?

Comment: Putting parenthesis does work! Thank you for reply. If you could also explain why `$` din work that would be amazing!

Comment: `$` is not equivalent to parentheses, but a way to *avoid* parenthesis, since `$` has a lower precedence than (nearly) any other operator.

Comment: @Yathi `2 : $ tail $ tail test` doesn't work for exactly the same reason that `5 * + 3 + 2` doesn't work.

Comment: @Yathi, but `(2:) $ tail $ tail test` and `(:) 2 $ tail $ tail test` will both work. `(:)` is the actual function corresponding to the `:` operator, and `(2 :)` is either `(:) 2` or `\x -> 2 : x` (I don't remember which and it very rarely matters).